# Redirect to order listing after order status change from admin panel - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order, order-status, redirection

In admin panel, after order status change from pending to complete, I want to redirect it to listing page.

**How can I redirect to order listing page straight after the order status change to complete?**